# Attach network disk as direct

Tags: windows, network-shares, nas, windows-server-2019, iscsi

Is there a way to attach a network disk as a direct without creating VHD etc? I want to connect drive directly from one computer to other by network by like iSCSI but without creating VHD.

Not acceptable:

1. Drive Bender
2. iSCSI (it is creating VHD drive)
3. Mapping as network drive (direct only like iSCSI but without creating VHD)
4. CLI-only linux
5. FreeNAS, TrueNAS, XigmaNAS, UNRAID, XPEnologi etc

Highly likely Windows/Windows Server program

Comment: What makes each of those options not acceptable? How are we supposed to know that the next suggestion won't fail the same mysterious criteria? (And, does iSCSI really require creating a VHD?)

Comment: @user1686 I just only want to connect network shared drive as direct drive without VHD etc. I want to data stores on the disk directly (not into container). Yes, it is. iSCSI really require creating a VHD

Comment: So... why is accessing the root share not an option then? eg: `\\pcname\c$` ?

Comment: So why did you rule out Linux, for example? Unlike Windows, it _is_ able to serve raw disks as iSCSI targets (as seen [e.g. at Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-iscsi)).

Comment: @user1686 I exclude CLI-only Linux. I am not into Linux and it is too difficult for me. Linux with GUI is acceptable! Can you attach a link to the "how-to" manual?

Comment: @LPChip I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: @user1686 RedHat is paid! I already have Windows Server!

Comment: You can access disks based on their administrative root share if you are an administrator. So lets say your server has name Server1, you can access the C drive by typing \\server1\c$ and login with the admin user account

Comment: @LPChip Okay. So how can I view this disc in disc management (computer management)? I need to system seen this disk and it should be placed in disc management.

Comment: If you want that, open computer management, right-click the first item and select " connect to ..." type name of server, and you can see computer management as if you access that computer directly.

Comment: @LPChip I need ATTACH this disc from one computer to another. NOT VIEW ONLY!!!!!!

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and not just tell what you want, but also WHY you want it, so we can help you get the right answer. So far all indicates that what you want isn't possible, but this is the classic sign of an X-Y problem. You have a problem, came up with a solution, and now need help with that solution even though the actual solution that you need is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you exclude iSCSI in your question I will still tell you that iSCSI is the best way to do this.

On the computer (let's cal it A) where the disk is physically attached you share the entire disk (*not a VHD on a disk*) as an iSCSI Target and simply connect to that from the other computer (B).

Please note that you better make sure that on computer A nothing, besides the iSCSI software, will attempt to use that disk or corruption will happen.
(Best remove all drive-letters from that disk on A so the OS on A can't touch it.)

Comment: But how to do that without VHD creating? Is where free Linux which contains this functional? And what kind of disk file system should be? Can you give me a link where I can read about Linux (free only) & iSCSI.

Comment: @Andy I never had any reason to try this on Linux, but the functionality is there, I'm sure. Debian package is called TGT. Google it. File system in Linux is irrelevant. You don't need/want one. You are sharing the whole DISK to the other computer. You can have the Windows computer do the partitioning and formatting with Disk Administrator. That is what you wanted anyway if I read your comments correctly.

Comment: But is it safe or not?

Comment: @Andy As long s as your network is reliable and on computer A you don't try to to anything with the disk (besides sharing it) there is nothing unsafe about this. This was the primary use-case for iSCSI (together with sharing tape-streamers) in the first place when iSCSI was first invented.

Comment: On linux you can install LIO target, which can be used to share block device via iSCSI. 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ISCSI/LIO
As an alternative, you can use StarWind VSAN free to do the same thing on Windows.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free

Comment: @Tonny Thank you

Comment: @Stuka thank you, I will to try

Comment: @Stuka I did it. Debian 10 + tgt and it is wonderful! Thank you!)

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck